# Questions using 'which'

Tags: grammar

I was in my English class yesterday where I was learning direct/indirect questions, and I tried to come up with examples of them. I thought it was going to be easy, but I ended up being confused about these three varieties of a question I thought of.

1. Which car is yours? / May I ask you which car yours is?
2. Which one is your car? / May I ask you which one your car is?
3. Which is your car? / May I ask you which your car is?

Are any of these grammatically wrong? Which one is the most natural?

Comment: If you're only asking which sentence is *better*, or if any are *wrong*, then you're asking for proofreading, which is off topic. Do you actually have a specific question about grammar?

Comment: All are correct. "May I ask you which one your car is?" is a bit awkward but still ok.  In all three indirect examples, in conversational English we would also use the syntax "May I ask you which car is yours?" (which technically would be written as *May I ask you, "Which car is yours?"*), but this is because in informal/spoken English we sometimes ignore the rules you're currently learning!

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Sorry I guess I asked for proofreading in a way, but what I really wanted to know was which one native speakers would generally use to ask this question.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please visit [ell.se] Good Luck.